# nodeJS auto sends dns query on start

Tags: node.js

Nodejs make a DNS query to "registry.npmjs.org" on start
and we want to know why and to prevent it if its necessary
I searched over the internet and havnt found a clue for this behaviour
this is how I start the server

```
 return https.createServer(mtls_options, app).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Running Node-server version: ${process.version}`);
  });
```

Comment: I don't think NodeJS itself makes that query. It's either NPM (even though I don't think a simple `npm start` causes that) or one of your dependencies.

Comment: @NullDev Im using node index.js so it cant be Npm

Comment: what are doing in the index.js? can you just put maybe a console.log in a js file and run with node to see if u get a dns query as well or not?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty great sugesstion ill try that

Comment: @NullDev you right its from the "npm start" command (I guess i do use it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that The DNS query doesnt executed by the NODE
but only when I start the server with "npm start"